# How to get the current location (lat/ long) of user using CLLocationManager?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I currently have an app that allows a user to check-in somewhere based on their current location.  The user will press the check-in button, the current user's location will be calculated and then an api call is made with the current users lat and long coordinates.  I'm new to CLLocationManager, how can I find the user's current location?

Comment: `locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude`

Comment: `locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude` (assuming you named your CLLocationManager instance "locationManager")